# Setup Heroku/Facebook on local environment

Tags: facebook, heroku, wampserver

I try to setup the Heroku/Facebook on my local environment (WampServer, Windows Xp) I have put this in my httpd.config file:

```
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
        DocumentRoot "C:\Documents and Settings\name\fold/"
        ServerName fold.local
        SetEnv FACEBOOK_APP_ID code
        SetEnv FACEBOOK_SECRET code
    </VirtualHost>
```

But when I am trying to reach fold.local I get **403 Forbidden** I am following this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common solution for this is to register two Facebook app IDs- one for local dev and another for your public site.  Add an entry to your HOSTS file on your local system to point the "DEV" app URL to your local site

For example: Register your "dev" app to the URL: http://dev.mysite.com

Then, add an entry in your HOSTS file for that URL pointing to localhost/127.0.0.1